# Unable to teleports assets from one chain to another chain through bridge

Tags: xcm, parity-bridges-common

I'm working on the parity-bridges-common where i was not enable to send assets from one chain to another.

I'm giving instruction of teleportation from one chain to another and it is showing me success[image]

And the event came to source chain explorer

[image]

But in the another chain it is showing this event. But it is not showing any xcm related messages neither it is transferring the tokens

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please examine the logs in your terminal to investigate any potential issues related to receiving messages between chains. Specifically, ensure that there are no delays or obstacles impacting the message reception process. It appears that the event displayed on the screen indicates successful receipt of the message, but there may be an underlying problem preventing the execution of the corresponding instruction.

Ensure that you carefully verify the weights you are utilizing to execute the function. It is crucial to confirm that the assigned weights are accurate and aligned with the intended execution of the function.